# API for methods on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing [Hartl's](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#sec-account_activation_emails) tutorial. I often don't know whether some methods mentioned in the tutorial are defined in Rails or in the code in the tutorial. I have problem finding methods when learning Rails. Does anyone know where I could find the API for:

```
edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email
```

in Listing 11.13? Can someone advise me how I could finding the methods' API in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is url helper, it's automatically created from `routes.rb`. You can find more in [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

In routes you have a line `resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]`
According to url generation rules it produces 1 route:

```
http://www.example.com/account_activations/:id/edit
```

Helper `edit_account_activation_url` takes id as a first parameter, it is `@user.activation_token` in your case. As a second parameter it takes query hash (we can omit {} for last hash parameter) - it is `{ email: @user.email }`. That how it works

You can solve the problem of "not finding the methods' API" by reading the guide together with the tutorial

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out the concept of `url helpers`, though now I know part of the reason for the method's existence, I still do not understand the full reason behind the method signature of`edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email:
   @user.email`

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth are you asking about the helper's name or about the arguments?

Comment: @ShiraElitzur the arguments right now, I got part of the answer regarding the name right here.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth, updated the answer. Check if it helps you to understand

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth these are the parameters that required for the action

Comment: @Vasilisa Hi, I think I get a better idea now. From your answer I can interpret it as we can get the required arguments as hinted from the url generation rules(Since `:id` is shown, there is a required first parameter), as for the second parameter, how would you know if the method would take it a hash or no hash, as I usually only know that only with an API.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth, to know exactly which parameters you can pass to the method you need to find it in the docs or use Pry (see great answer by Sergio Tulentsev). As you can see, all url helpers takes optionally hash parameter

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone advise me how I could finding the methods' API in general?

Good question. I use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

```
[3] pry(main)> show-source app.users_path

From: /home/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb @ line 342:
Owner: #<Module:0x0000563dd616fc28>
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 5

define_method(name) do |*args|
  options = nil
  options = args.pop if args.last.is_a? Hash
  helper.call self, args, options
end
```

In this particular case, it's much less helpful than the routing guide mentioned by @Vasilisa. But at least it gives you a hint. And it's very useful generally. Especially when you're dealing with, say, a gem/library which uses inheritance/mixins heavily and you're never quite sure which of 30 `call` implementations you're invoking here. This approach shows exact location and source code.

Answer (score 0):

A good source of information is [APIdock](https://apidock.com). This site allows you to do a search against Ruby or Rails for API information.  What is useful is that users will add additional code snippets or comments about the methods on the API

The other source of just Rails API is at [Ruby on Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/). This typically gives you the latest API information. Comparatively the APIdock site will show the different Rails release version on the version timeline at the top of the page

Comment: Hi, I know of these sources already, but the problem is I don't know where the segment of code falls under in the API.

Comment: Hi. So in your example you are trying to work out where edit_account_activation_url is located in the API?  Apart from using search which would then fail on the rails api you’d only be able to assume that it’s a custom method

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to figure out where `edit_account_activation_url` is located and its respective arguments. I don't know where to find such information about the "custom method" either.